# Does UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction be applied to the views animated or the whole screen?

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

According to documentation this call

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    someView.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

is equivalent to

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
     someView.alpha = 1.0;
 } completion:nil];
```

– thus not passing along the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option. What happens if this option is not added?

Will all views in the animation (in this example `someView`) not receive any user interaction or does it apply to the whole screen?

All I find in the documentation is

> UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
>   Allow the user to interact with views while they are being animated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It affects only the views that are animated. Not the whole screen.